# How to push new wallet into Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: web3js, wallets, hd-wallets

Imagine that I generated normally encrypted(by Ethereum standards) wallet keys(private, public). How to push this generated wallet into Ethereum node?
Is it possible to push new wallet into node, using web3js library? Or is it enough to send some ethereums to a new wallet address, so new address will automatically placed into blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "pushing" a wallet to an Ethereum node. You can go ahead and send ether to the new address. When you want to send ether *from* that address, you'll need to know the corresponding private key (which you already generated).